# How to create menu items combining icon and text with vuetify 2.x?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need to create a menu with some checked menu items. This is for toggle options.

The check icon should be shown and removed in front of the menu item when the item is clicked. Ideally, the menu should not close when the toggle menus are selected.

Making a dialog with switches would be inconvenient because it would require multiple clicks to perform the operation and the user wouldn't have a direct feedback on the effect. The toggle menu items modify the filtering rule of a displayed list.

My current code has the toggle menu items but there is no feedback for the user with check icons.

Not sure if checked menus are compatible with material design.

**Edit**: Adding an icon to a menu item is very simple.

```html
          <v-list-item @click="maskZero">
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ $i18n.t("list.maskZero") }}
            </v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-icon v-bind:class="showWhenMaskZero">
              <v-icon> mdi-check </v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
          </v-list-item>
```

```js
  // . . .
  computed: {
    showWhenMaskZero() {
      return {
        "d-none": !this.$store.maskZero,
      };
    },
  },
```

What is not working is toggling its visibility. The `showWhenMaskZero()` function is only called the first time the menu is displayed.

How could I force an update of the menu content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in vue you have two command at your disposal which you can use on the element to control its visibility or rendering state, these two are `v-if` and `v-show`, the difference is that `v-if="true"` actually renders the element to the DOM while `v-show="true"` simply controls its visibility.

so what you can do is use `v-show` or `v-if` and pass to them an expression resulting to either `true` or `false` or simply pass to them a variable of type `boolean` and control that variable's value through your `onclick` method.

check the example below to get a hint:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    lists: [
      { id: 1, title: 'one', isChecked: false },
      { id: 2, title: 'two', isChecked: false },
      { id: 3, title: 'three', isChecked: false },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    toggleSelection(selectedItemId) {
      const selectedItem = this.lists.find((item) => item.id === selectedItemId);
      selectedItem.isChecked = !selectedItem.isChecked;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item v-for="{id, title, isChecked} in lists" :key="id" @click="toggleSelection(id)">
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ title }}
            </v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-icon v-show="isChecked">
              <v-icon> mdi-check </v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the v-if and v-show. Missed that. I'm a beginner. But unfortunately it doesn't work with my menu. I added `v-if="computedFunction"` on the `v-list-item-icon` element. The computed function simply return the boolean value of a variable in my vuex store. With a breakpoint I could see that the computed function is called the first time the menu is displayed, and not anymore after it. This is the problem I have. Is there a way to force the menu to be re-rendered when the  menu item is clicked ?

Comment: it would help if you shared your vuex code but generally computed values are called at first then they cache the result for later use and don't run again unless some of their dependent values change. then they run agian, calculate the new result, cache that value until the dependencies change again

Comment: I'm aware that compute caches the result. I assumed that the vuex store field is a dependent value. It is updated by the method called by the menu item @click event. The method calls a vuex commit method to change the variable.  I don't fully understand yet how this vue triggering works. My code is too complex to show here. Sorry.

Comment: since I can't see the code its hard to tell but i have a question. what is `this.$store.maskZero` ? is it a state in vuex store?

Comment: It finally works. I made a stupid mistake. It worked when using a variable defined in data. The error is that I retrieved the value in the vuex store with the expression `this.$store.maskZero`while it should have been `this.$store.state.maskZero`. Once I fixed that it worked. Your help was precious. Thank you very much for taking the time to look into my problem.

Comment: I suspected that if it's a `state` then this way of calling it is not correct. you're welcome. glad i could help

Comment: It is correct. I verified in the documentation and tested it.  It is even possible to write this `<v-list-item-icon v-if="this.$store.state.maskZero">`. vuex is very convenient and powerful.